# Perforce: command line to list files marked for delete

Tags: command-line, perforce

I have files that are marked for delete in my workspace (but not yet submitted).  Now I want them to be listed at command line.  I have tried the following command without success.

```
p4 diff -sd "C:\myworkspace\..."
```

I could not find any option in the diff command to list files that are marked for delete.  Is it another command, or a hidden option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you are looking for is [p4 opened](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/opened.html)

```
C:\Proj\test>p4 opened
//depot/Test/_header.txt#5 - delete default change (text)
//depot/Test/personnel_updates.sql#1 - add default change (text)
```

You would probably want to filter the output to only include the files as marked for delete (you can see I have an add and delete on the default changelist).

```
C:\Proj\test>p4 opened | findstr " - delete "
//depot/Test/_header.txt#5 - delete default change (text)
```

Note: You can also use the `-c` parameter to specify a certain changelist if you have placed your changes on a numbered changelist.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use **fstat**:

```
p4 fstat -Ro -F "action=delete" -T depotFile,clientFile //...
```

Comment: I ran into this situation of mass marking for deletion. Since the files I actually had changed were not marked for deletion, the command you provided was invaluable.